# How to keep images in same aspect ratio in CSS when using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I've got many images laid out with flexbox. Most of the images have a 2:1 aspect ratio but some don't (can be too wide or too high). I'd like those images to stay within the 2:1 aspect ratio anyway.

In https://jsfiddle.net/5h0gx7L4/ you can see the box that's too wide is fine and stays within the 2:1 aspect ratio (not sure but maybe because `flex-basis` controls the width), but the one that's too high breaks out of the 2:1 aspect ratio even though it should be contained.

I can't use any hardcoded heights because it's a fluid and responsive design and everything scales up and down as you change the size of the window. But the divs containing the images should have a 2:1 aspect ratio so that any images inside are contained within it and don't get bigger.

```css
div
{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div > div {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><img src=https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A></div>
  <div><img src=https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A></div>
  <div><img src=https://placeholder.pics/svg/800x200/FF9A9A></div>
  <div><img src=https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A></div>
  <div><img src=https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A></div>
  <div><img src=https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x400/FF9A9A></div>
  <div><img src=https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A few years ago, I started using `background-image` instead of `img` just because dealing with the exact situation you've posted. If you want to maintain semantics, you can keep the `img` tag in there, but hide it.

Comment: did you tried `object-fit: cover;` ?

Comment: @pavelbere Yes try it in the jsfiddle it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div > div {
    flex-basis: 25%;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 12.5%;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A"></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A"></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/800x200/FF9A9A"></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A"></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A"></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x400/FF9A9A"></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/400x200/FF9A9A"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try it out. How can I change it for different aspect ratios?

Comment: Adjust the bottom padding of the wrapper element for each image. As Lars said, this is for a 2:1 ratio. If, for example, you wanted 16:9, it would be 14.06%. The percentage value for the padding refers to the width of the wrapper's parent though, so it may be desirable to use the `:after` pseudo-element to set it instead so it will refer to the width of the wrapper (remember that the pseudo-element would need something like `content:'\a0';display:block;height:0` as well.).

Comment: [This might be related to a bug in Chrome 74](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=958802)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height to zero and use `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` for the aspect ratio since it’s based on the element’s width. In your case it should look like this:

```
div > div {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 12.5%; /* 25/2 = 2:1 */
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39p2cqzn/1/)

**Edit: Ignore my answer, see comments and Kravimir's solution**

Comment: Is it working for you? The jsfiddle just shows 2 thin lines and nothing else for me.

Comment: Like a charm https://i.imgur.com/HvHySBj.png (excuse the mobile screenshot, I’m on the road)

Comment: It looked like that for you on desktop too? Appearing very differently for me in firefox and chrome. Could someone else check and see how it looks on desktop and let me know if it's just me?

Comment: Yes, it looks identically for me in all major browsers on both desktop and mobile

Comment: Curious. It doesn't seem to be working here either. Removing `height:100%` from `img`  fixes it in Firefox, but Chrome is being difficult.

Comment: Alright, I'm at work now and it's broken in Chrome and Firefox on Debian but still works for me in all browsers on the Mac, Kravimir's answer runs fine on everthing I could test